# Guestimating managed package protected custom setting usage in subscriber org

Tags: managed-package, customsetting, limits, org

We are using a managed package that has a protected custom setting that stores some additional information per user. We have 6000 users roughly and our org has 9 user licenses so that means amount of cached data allowed is 9 MB.

We started getting an error: CUSTOM_SETTINGS_LIMIT_EXCEEDED for that protected custom setting.

Not having much options in dealing with protected custom settings, we contacted Salesforce and had our limits increased to 20 MB. The custom settings usage screen also tells me that we are only using 2 MB of our 20 MB limit Now we are no longer getting the error however we would like to gauge as to the usage of that protected setting. Since SF gave us 20 MB, does it also mean that the managed package limits are now 20 MB also for that package? There is some confusion I have there in terms of whether this initial limit warning was due to manage package hitting it's own 9 MB limit as opposed to the org limit of 9 mb.

Basically did 6000 users result in 9 MB to be reached and by that logic will 12000-14000 users can cause this 20 MB limit to be reached???

I am unable to see the protected custom setting usage in the SF UI.  How can I guestimate how many additional users it would take to hit our org limit? Or how taxing is this managed package against our org limits and how much time do we have before we hit the limits.

We have contacted the managed package vendor and they are working on a patch but we need to mitigate a risk.  Is there something we can do or can Salesforce provide insights on custom setting usage by a managed package in one's org?

Any ideas?